# How to add logic to columns in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently, I am using Snowflake, and I have to extract a string within an URL. This would tell me what kind of activity is going on in the data. I am using the following code:

```
SELECT [WAREHOUSE].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA]
AS
log:event_type AS event_type,
log:blah_blah_blah
```

Basically, I want to see if the event_type contains a particular phrase. For example, the event_type may contain the phrase "directory." If that is the case, I would like to add another column that only says "directory."

I'd imagine that the code would contain logic along the lines of:

```
CASE
WHEN CONTAINS(event_type, "directory") THEN "directory"
```

But how exactly could we make that happen? I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for your guys' help!

Comment: If you want to apply logic to your data, you should use a view.  Is that your question or are you looking for the exact SQL logic?  Also, you mention both Snowflake and MySQL in your tags.  Which one are you seeking assistance with?

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize mySQL was another database. I am using Snowflake. Would you just include the logic within the list of columns?

Comment: Do you have a working query? The ones in the question don't seem to be getting data from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression with `like`

```
(CASE WHEN event_type LIKE '%directory%' THEN 'directory'
 END)
```